# problem building bidi package

Tags: xetex, packages, bidi

I downloaded the most current zip file for the 'bidi' package from CTAN and attempted to build it.

First I ran `sudo latex bidi.ins` which ran with no errors. Next, I ran this: `sudo latex bidi.dtx`

which throws this error:

```
! Fatal fontspec error: "cannot-use-pdftex"
```

and indicates either XeLaTeX or LuaTeX must be used instead to build it. So I tried this:

```
sudo xelatex bidi.dtx
```

which throws this error:

```
! fontspec error: "font-not-found"
! 
! The font "Minion Pro" cannot be found.
```

Seems odd this package should look for a specific font.

I tried installing the bidi package through a texlive package available through the Debian (XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99996 TeX Live 2016/Debian for stretch and jessie) package installer, but that version of bidi throws errors like this one when run with XeLaTeX:

```
! LaTeX Error: Command \XeTeX already defined.
```

Can anyone point me to a version of bidi that actually works?

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you install the package using the package manager? You are failing to compile the documentation of the `bidi` package. If you have created the `sty` file, the package is available.

Comment: As I mentioned, I tried that through the Debian package installer. That version of bidi, quoted above, throws errors.

Comment: I didn't read that far.I also don't recommend the Linux versions of TeX Live, rather the vanilla version as distributed by the TeX user group.

Comment: @hilbert: Apparently Debian is still providing outdated packages etc. I recommend to use the `TeXLive` net installer, which allows for updating the whole TeX distribution at any time (apart from the period where TL is frozen from April to June)

Comment: Perhaps, which is why I tried installing the most recent version of bidi from from CTAN, which is presumably the same one I'm going to get from the TexLive net installer. But, as I mentioned, that version doesn't build cleanly on my system. The bidi.sty file that does get built gives the same errors as what appear with the Debian package.

Comment: @hilbert: I think the basic problem is that downloading `bidi.dtx` is not enough because there are cross-dependencies between packages etc. If any of the other packages (on which `bidi` relies) changed in the meantime as well you will get into troubles, most likely. You need a thorough update, just parts of the distribution. That's the advantage of using a distribution manager like `tlmgr` or MikTeX's facilities

Comment: you say "Seems odd this package should look for a specific font." it does not look for the font when the package is used, that was when you were running xelatex on bidi.dtx, that is typesetting its documentation, that document uses a specific font. But bidi has lots of dependencies it really makes it hard to install just bidi, by hand. Either use the debian package manager if using the debian texlive, or use tlmgr if using texlive from tug.

Comment: @David -- When bidi is installed through the Debian package manager, the bidi package throws errors as I mentioned in my original post. This is part of what caused me to go down the road I have. An interesting thing is, the errors don't happen with the TeX Live 2014 version of bidi. If I copy that into my 2016 texlive tree (the latest Debian offers), then things work fine. I'll try the DVD image. Thanks to all the respondents.

Comment: you didn't show any example of the failure but `\XeTeX` being defined twice seems more related to loading two packages in the the same document (and just putting `\let\XeTeX=\relax` would avoid that, but are you sure it is related to bidi,  `bidi` does not define `\XeTeX` as far as I can see.

Comment: Good call David. The core issue appears to be specifying '\usepackage{xltxtra}'. This worked in my document for many years, but in TeX Live 2016, it causes a problem, and the error message doesn't really give a good hint as to how to resolve it. Incidentally, building bidi by manually (except for the docs) seems to work in my case. Thanks for the assistance.

Comment: There is very little reason to load `xlxtra` apart from `fontspec` (which you should load directly, the other packages it loads are rarely if ever needed.

Comment: Appreciated. Maybe this should be the subject of a separate topic, but is there any central location that discusses deprecated/unneeded packages? 'xltxtra' (likely borrowed from a template) existed benignly for years in my document. Since backward compatibility of packages can't be guaranteed, and runtime messages can be a little cryptic, a central collection of 'questionable package' information would be useful. While Stack Exchange is a welcome resource, finding information is a little like playing pin the tail on the donkey sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

The core issue was this command:

```
\usepackage{xltxtra}
```

causes errors to be given when using TeX Live 2016 packages in conjunction with polyglossia and bidirectional languages. I've only seen this in a Debian-based installation, but it may appear elsewhere. Prior to the 2016 build, xltxtra didn't cause a problem.